# fetch one row from oci8 oracle database

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I have a function that returns one row from an oracle table.

I am new to returning data from oci8. I am hoping you could help me with optimizing the function in regard to returning one result.

I thought about adding ROWNUM = 1 to the sql, but wasn't sure if that was the best case. Also, returning index 0 of the $course_listing['SUBJ_DESC'] seems sloppy.

```
function getSubject($term_code = false, $subj_code = false)
{
    if(!$term_code || !$subj_code)
        return false;

    $stid = oci_parse($this->conn, "SELECT SUBJECT_DESC FROM szvcourses WHERE TERM_CODE = '{$term_code}' AND SUBJ_CODE = '{$subj_code}'");

    oci_execute($stid);
    oci_fetch_all($stid, $course_listing);

    if(count($course_listing['SUBJECT_DESC']) == 0)
        return false;

    return $course_listing['SUBJECT_DESC'][0];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no PHP programmer, but it looks like you are constructing an SQL statement that contains the search values. Doing so is bad.

Reason 1:  SQL injection http://xkcd.com/327/

Reason 2.  Oracle has a pool of recent SQLs. If the SQL is already in the pool, Oracle won't have to parse the SQL again.

You should use parameters instead. The code should look something like this (the syntax is incorrect, because I don't know PHP):

```
   $stid = oci_parse($this->conn, "SELECT SUBJECT_DESC FROM szvcourses WHERE TERM_CODE = ? AND SUBJ_CODE = ?");
   oci_set_string_parameter($stid, 1, {$term_code}); 
   oci_set_string_parameter($stid, 2, {$subj_code});
```

Comment: Thanks, using oci_bind_by_name w/ ROWNUM = 1

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to return only one row then incorporating `WHERE ROWNUM = 1` would be best.  This approach ensures that the only data you're working with is the exact data that you want.

```
SELECT SUBJECT_DESC FROM szvcourses WHERE TERM_CODE = '{$term_code}' AND SUBJ_CODE = '{$subj_code}' AND ROWNUM = 1");
```